# p:autocomplete SelectEvent#getObject() returns null

Tags: jsf, events, primefaces, autocomplete

once autocomplete form is submitted and AJAX invoke handleSelect method - I recieve event correctly (like example : org.primefaces.event.SelectEvent[source=org.primefaces.component.autocomplete.AutoComplete@3d7b6188]) , but in next step event.getObject() is null. I think maybe there is a problem with Casting.

1) FORM

```
<p:autoComplete 
            id="searchArticle"
            value="#{articleBean.selectedArticle}" 
            completeMethod="#{articleBean.complete}" 
            var="article"
            itemValue="#{article}"
            itemLabel="#{article.articleName}" 
            converter="articleConverter" >

        <p:ajax event="itemSelect" listener="#{articleBean.handleSelect}" update=":searchForm:message"/>

                        </p:autoComplete>
```

2) handleSelect method

```
 public void handleSelect(SelectEvent event){

            System.out.println("handleSelect - event=" + event);
            // returns example : org.primefaces.event.SelectEvent[source=org.primefaces.component.autocomplete.AutoComplete@7dffb095]

            Article a = ((Article) event.getObject());
            System.out.println("handleSelect - object=" + a);   // returns null

    }
```

3) ArticleBean

```
package bean;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Model;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.validation.constraints.Min;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Pattern;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

import org.primefaces.event.SelectEvent;

import business.ArticleService;
import model.Article;


@Model
public class ArticleBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4080308091985560927L;


    private int articlePrice;
    private String articleNumber;
    private String articleName;
    private String articleDescription;

    // for Search field
    private Article selectedArticle;
    private List<Article> articles = new ArrayList<Article>();


    // EJB 
    @Inject
    ArticleService articleService;

    // Default Constructor
    public ArticleBean() {
        super();
    }


    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        articles = articleService.getArticles();
    }

    // search - suggestions
     public List<Article> complete(String query) {
         List<Article> suggestions = new ArrayList<Article>();
         for(Article article : articles) {
                if(article.getArticleName().startsWith(query) || article.getArticleDescription().startsWith(query)) {
                    suggestions.add(article);
                }
            }
            return suggestions;
      }


     // after Search selected
     public void handleSelect(SelectEvent event){

            System.out.println("handleSelect - event=" + event);
            // returns example : org.primefaces.event.SelectEvent[source=org.primefaces.component.autocomplete.AutoComplete@7dffb095]

            Article a = ((Article) event.getObject());
            System.out.println("handleSelect - object=" + a);   // returns null

    }

        public String save() {

            System.out.println("Saving..." + this.articleName + " " + this.articleDescription);

            Article article = new Article();
            article.setArticleNumber(articleNumber);
            article.setArticlePrice(articlePrice);
            article.setArticleDescription(articleDescription);
            article.setArticleName(articleName);

            articleService.save(article);

            addMessage("New Product created");
            return("index");
        }   


        public void addMessage(String summary){
            FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, summary, null);
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null,message);
        }



// Getters and Setters

    // 1.ArticleNumber 

    // format "xx-1234567890"
    @Pattern(regexp="[A-Z]{2}-[0-9]{1,10}$", message="Number : Format AA-1111111")
    public String getArticleNumber() {
        return articleNumber;
    }

    public void setArticleNumber(String articleNumber) {
        this.articleNumber = articleNumber;
    }

    // 2.ArticleName

    @NotNull(message="Name : Must be inserted")                                     // nenulove
    @Pattern(regexp="[a-zA-Z0-9-_\\s+]{3,30}$", message="Name : Invalid characters inserted")   // povolene znaky : male, Velke, cisla a -,_,   $ = konec Stringu
    @Size(min=3, max=30, message="Name : Invalid lenght (should be 3-30)")          // delka Stringu min 3 a max 30
    public String getArticleName() {
        return articleName;
    }

    public void setArticleName(String articleName) {
        this.articleName = articleName;
    }

    // 3.ArticlePrice

    @Min(1)     // hodnota min 1
    public int getArticlePrice() {
        return articlePrice;
    }


    public void setArticlePrice(int articlePrice) {
        this.articlePrice = articlePrice;
    }


    // 4. ArticleDescription

    public String getArticleDescription() {
        return articleDescription;
    }

    public void setArticleDescription(String articleDescription) {
        this.articleDescription = articleDescription;
    }

    public static long getSerialversionuid() {
        return serialVersionUID;
    }



    public Article getSelectedArticle() {
        return selectedArticle;
    }


    public void setSelectedArticle(Article selectedArticle) {
        this.selectedArticle = selectedArticle;
    }



    public List<Article> getArticles() {
        return articles;
    }


    public void setArticles(List<Article> articles) {
        this.articles = articles;
    }



}
```

4) Article

```
package model;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.Table;


@NamedQueries(
        {
            @NamedQuery(name=Article.GET_ARTICLE_BY_ID, query="Select a From Article a where a.id = :id"),
            @NamedQuery(name=Article.GET_ALL_ARTICLE, query="Select a From Article a")
        }
)
@Entity
@Table(name="article")
public class Article {

    public static final String GET_ALL_ARTICLE      = "Article.get_all_articles";
    public static final String GET_ARTICLE_BY_ID    = "Article.get_article_by_id";

    private int id;
    private double articlePrice;
    private String articleNumber;  
    private String articleName;
    private String articleDescription;



    public Article() {
        super();
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    public String getArticleNumber() {
        return articleNumber;
    }

    public void setArticleNumber(String articleNumber) {
        this.articleNumber = articleNumber;
    }


    public String getArticleName() {
        return articleName;
    }

    public void setArticleName(String articleName) {
        this.articleName = articleName;
    }

    public String getArticleDescription() {
        return articleDescription;
    }

    public void setArticleDescription(String articleDescription) {
        this.articleDescription = articleDescription;
    }


    public double getArticlePrice() {
        return articlePrice;
    }

    public void setArticlePrice(double articlePrice) {
        this.articlePrice = articlePrice;
    }
}
```

5) ARTICLE CONVERTER

```
package convertor;

import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.convert.Converter;
import javax.faces.convert.FacesConverter;

import model.Article;

@FacesConverter(value="articleConverter")
public class ArticleConverter implements Converter {


    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String submittedValue) {

        if(submittedValue.trim() == null || submittedValue.trim().isEmpty())
            return null;
        else
        {
            Article article = new Article();
            article.setArticleName(submittedValue); 
            return article;
        }


    }

    // we dont use it 
    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object object) {

        return null;
    }


}
```

Comment: Just a little rec, why don't you use a generic entity converter? Like the one included in Omnifaces, just add a good **toString()** implementation to your Entity.

http://showcase.omnifaces.org/converters/SelectItemsConverter

Comment: @mcastilloy2k: SelectItemsConverter requires f:selectItems which is not used by p:autoComplete. Better use ListConverter http://showcase.omnifaces.org/converters/ListConverter